# .NET XML serialization tags missing if not initialized

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a problem with .NET XML serialization.
If I deserialize XML without certain tags and serialize this object back to XML some of these tags will be skipped. Parameter-less constructor sets these properties to default values, and they have both getters and setters.

Only `int` attributes are skipped, `String` are serialized.

Input file:

```
<FileList>
  <File>
    <FilePath>RE.msg</FilePath>
  </File>
</FileList>
```

Output file:

```
<FileList GUID="A13EDDDF-F55A-4540-A776-609245B92D83" Created="2012-08-23T09:46:30+03:00">
  <File GUID="28C6E090-A3D5-4CD7-97A6-7A46F2F0DDF7" Created="2012-08-23T09:46:30+03:00">
    <FilePath>RE.msg</FilePath>
    <FileStamp>wjoeao1x.msg</FileStamp>
    <StatusMessage>Created</StatusMessage>
  </File>
</FileList>
```

Parameter-less constructor sets value for `int` property `Status` but it doesn't get serialized:

```
public CT_File()
{
    Status = 1;
    StatusMessage = "Created";
}
```

Class definition. It is auto-generated from XSD schema.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
//[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class CT_File : CT_Base {

    private string filePathField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private string fileStampField;

    private string kapprisIDField;

    private int statusField;

    private bool statusFieldSpecified;

    private string statusMessageField;

    private int errorCodeField;

    private bool errorCodeFieldSpecified;

    private string errorMessageField;

    private CT_FileList attachmentsField;

    private string originalIDField;

    public CT_File()
    {
        Status = 1;
        StatusMessage = "Created";
        this.attachmentsField = new CT_FileList();
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FilePath {
        get {
            return this.filePathField;
        }
        set {
            this.filePathField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FileStamp {
        get {
            return this.fileStampField;
        }
        set {
            this.fileStampField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string KapprisID {
        get {
            return this.kapprisIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.kapprisIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool StatusSpecified {
        get {
            return this.statusFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.statusFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string StatusMessage {
        get {
            return this.statusMessageField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusMessageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int ErrorCode {
        get {
            return this.errorCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.errorCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ErrorCodeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.errorCodeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.errorCodeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ErrorMessage {
        get {
            return this.errorMessageField;
        }
        set {
            this.errorMessageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public CT_FileList Attachments {
        get {
            return this.attachmentsField;
        }
        set {
            this.attachmentsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OriginalID {
        get {
            return this.originalIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.originalIDField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the property / fields relating to `Status` and `StatusMessage` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XmlSerializer only serializes public fields/properties, and for properties: only if they have both a getter and setter. For example:

```
private int Status;
```

is not serialized, nor is:

```
private int status;
public int Status { get { return status; } }
```

or:

```
private int status;
public int Status { get { return status; } private set { status = value; } }
```

or:

```
public int Status { get; protected set; }
```

Additionally, members are not serialized if they are marked `[XmlIgnore]`, or if there is a method matching the name-based pattern:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeStatus() { return false; }
```

There is a second pattern that works the same, but allows 2-way checking (i.e. both "should I serialize this?" and "did this get a value during deserialization?"):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool StatusSpecified { get {...} set {...} }
```

Additionally, values that match their explicit default are not serialized:

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public int Status { get; set; } // won't serialize if ===1
```

My guess would be that it is not serializing for one of the above reasons.

Comment: Thanks for a lot of tips. I've added full code of class in my question. Unfortunately, none of your notes are applicable for the code. `Status` is just a public property w/ both getter and setter.

Comment: @keaukraine ah, I should have noted: `StatusSpecified` works the same as `ShouldSerializeStatus()`. Your code has a `StatusSpecified`. I will edit to clarify. But: set that to true, or more simply: remove it.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. Accessibility modifiers were the key.